# iOS UICollectionView cells' transition/slide in animation when they are about to appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

What I already have: a horizontally scrolled `UICollectionView`, and its cells (just a single line of cells).

What I want to do: animate the cells when they are about to appear -- `cells` slide in from right (outside the screen) to left, eventually stop at the left border of the `UICollectionView`.

How could I achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Question explained in this picture...]

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the collectionView.contentInset.  Set it to UIEdigeInsets with a negative x value equal to the collectionView.bounds.size.width.  You can use inherited scroll view methods to setContentOffset:animated: starting at offset zero, and animating to contentOffset == collectionView.bounds.size.width

Comment: Think right way will be re-implement collection view layout, or for easier way you can try to use delegate's method `willDisplayCell:` with specific insets

Comment: @danh thanks. after some searching on internet, it seems that animating contentInset will do the work, in the same way as you suggested. let me try this first and follow you up : ]

Comment: @IgorKislyuk thank you. will try this now and see what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the collectionView cell from their position to previous cell position by using following method

```
[collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath toIndexPath:toIndexPath];
```

I have implement same animation in collection view as given bellow :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let myreact = cell.frame
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x+320, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height)

         let value = Double(indexPath.row)*0.1
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay:value, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

            cell.frame = CGRect(x: myreact.origin.x+100, y: myreact.origin.y, width: myreact.size.width, height: myreact.size.height)

         }) { (finish) in

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: {
                cell.frame = myreact
            })
        }
    }

}
```

Try with it in Swift 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating the cells/the layout, I animate the `UICollectionView`, whose background color is `[UIColor clearColor]`...